# Is there an htaccess in IIS?

Tags: caching, manifest

In [Setting up offline viewing using the cache manifest](http://www.lynda.com/HTML-5-tutorials/ios-4-web-applications-with-html5-and-css3/69792-2.html) from Lynda.com, the author states that IF I'M USING AN APACHE SERVER, then I need to put my cache.manifest file in a subfolder with an .htaccess file so that the cache.manifest file isn't cached itself.

Q: If I'm not using Apache, but IIS instead, then is there an equivalent file, or maybe there's no need for an .htaccess file to ensure that my cache.manifest file is not being cached.

Answer (score 0):

`web.config` is the IIS version of .htaccess.

Here's a doc on some of .htaccess conversions: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Edit: there's also this: http://www.helicontech.com/ape/

Answer (score 0):

This is old but still works just fine. A FREE version that has been discontinued:

https://heliconapefree.weebly.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34836191)